What is the expected size of the smallest hitting set?
Suppose we pick $n$ subsets of size $j$ of an $N$-element set $S$ uniformly at random. A hitting set is a subset of $S$ that intersects all our subsets. I am interested in the smallest size of an hitting set.
What is its expected value?
For example for $n=2$, we get that the smallest cardinality is one, if the chosen sets are not disjoint and two if they are. The probability that two chosen subsets are disjoint is
$\prod_{i=N-j}^{N-2j-1}\frac{i}{N}$. Now I am looking at a formula/good approximation of the general case.
In general the problem to find a minimal hitting set is NP-hard, so it might be quite difficult to say something by hand. But sometimes finding expected values turns out to be easier than solving specific cases, so I still have not lost hope yet that an explicit formula might be possible.

If we fix a hitting set, it shouldn't be too hard to calculate the probability it's correct. The problem is that there may be many hitting sets with minimal size, and I don't know how to account for that

I hope this approach might give a reasonable lower bound regardless, but for an upper bound you'd have to account for repetition

Set cover problem. It is the same problem as what is the minimal number of boxes having balls of every color. I mean we have boxes with colored balls in them and we need to choose boxes in which every color can be found –

Yes you can dualize this problem, e.g. consider the sets as new elements and each original element as the set of all the sets that contain this element. Then the hitting set problem gets translated to the set cover problem. I have no idea how to translate the assumption that we pick sets of fixed size uniformly at random.

I don't know how to give a formula for the mean. However the following gives an approach that is often useful asymptotically. Its success depends on the relation between $n$, $N$, $j$, which you did not specify.
Let $A_k$ denote the $k$th random subset. Fix a parameter $l$. Define the random variable
$Z_l=\sum_{B\subset S: |B|\leq l} \prod_{k=1}^n 1_{B\cap A_k\neq \emptyset}$.
Note that $Z_l\geq 1$ iff there is a hitting set of size $\leq l$. That is
your minimal hitting set is precisely the minimal $l$ such that $Z_l\geq 1$.
The advantage of $Z_l$ is that its mean and second moment are easily computed. For example, if I did not make a mistake,
$$ EZ_l=\sum_{m=1}^l\binom{N}{m}(1- \frac{(N-m-j)!(N-j)!}{(N-m)! N!})^n$$
and a similar expression can be written for $EZ_l^2$ (it is uglier but certainly amenable to asymptotic analysis) — just decompose according to the number of sets $B_1,B_2$ of size $m_1,m_2\leq l$ and overlap $m_3$.
Now, your minimal set is certainly larger  with high probability
(when parameters go to infinity in some way, as you hinted in your discussion on NP hardness)
than any $l=l(N,n,j)$ for which $EZ_l\to 0$. Similarly, it is certainly smaller than any $l$ for which $EZ_l\to \infty$ AND $EZ_l^2/(EZ_l)^2\leq C$ with good probability (close to 1 if $C\sim 1$) because $$P(Z_l\geq 1)\geq (EZ_l)^2/EZ_l^2$$
which follows from Cauchy–Schwarz.
Often, this gives excellent estimates, and I believe will do so here as well, depending on the asymptotic you choose for your parameters.

A greedy algorithm lets us pick an element that it's at least $\lceil j n/N \rceil $ of the sets, leaving us with at most $n- \lceil j n/N \rceil $ subsets of size $j$ of an $N-1$-element set. We can iterate this process. The upper bound for the set $S$ we get from this is around $ \log n / (j/N)$ in some ranges.
I expect the upper bound from the greedy algorithm to be close to sharp in some regimes, which removes the need for the second moment estimate mentioned by ofer zeitouni.

This problem has a few different regimes. When $nj^2/N$ is small the average subset overlaps less than one other subset, and we can just choose the hitting set to be all elements lying in two or more subsets plus one element from each subset which does not overlap any other subset. The size of the minimal hitting set will be $n - n^2j^2/(2N)$ plus lower-order terms.
When $nj /N \log N$ is large, every element is in approximately the same number of subsets and the greedy bound should be close to sharp, with the first moment lower bound of ofer zeitouni probably sufficient to prove this.
In between these the situation is more complicated.

I wonder what is the efficiency of the classical Rogers approach here: choose $m$ elements to include into your hitting set at random and then just choose one element from each set that hasn't been hit yet. Compute the expectation (that is relatively easy for given $N,j,n$) and optimize over $m$. I will try to figure it out myself at some point, but the next few days are too busy, so if you beat me to it, I will be happy to read your assessment instead :-)

@fedjs I think it may do similarly to what I am calling the greedy algorithm, which chooses an element that has in at least the average number of sets, since a random elemnent will be in approximately the average number of sets. A variant that may be analyzable is to choose every element that is in more than $c$ sets and then choose one element from each remaining set.
